# Excel - partition running total

Tags: excel-formula

I have table:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | False |
| 8 | True |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | False |
| 4 | False |
| 9 | True |
| 5 | False |
| 7 | True |

When Running total comes to 10, in B I need True and start again running total from 0.

Explanation of calculation up to total of 10 (or greater)

1. row : 2 >= 10 = false
2. row : 2 + 8 >= 10 = true
3. row : 2 >= 10 = false
4. row : 2 + 3 >= 10 = false
5. row : 2 + 3 + 4 >= 10 = false
6. row : 2 + 3 + 4 + 9 >= 10 = true
7. row : 5 >= 10 = false
8. row : 5 + 7 >= 10 = true

I need formula for that.
I try with inverse running total, with modulo, but without succes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For avoiding OFFSET I used a data range that starts in row 2 (to be able to refer to the current row minus one).
So if the data is in cells `A2:A9` you could use the following formula in `B2`:

`=IF(ROW()=2,A2>=10,SUM(INDEX(A:A,MAX((B$1:B1=TRUE)*ROW(B$1:B1))+1):A2)>=10)`

In row 2 it checks if the value in A2 is greater than or equal to 10 (TRUE/FALSE). In the next rows it searches the maximum row number prior to the current row in column B to mention TRUE. It indexes column A from that calculated row number (+1, because you start counting after that row) up to the current row and checks the sum is greater than or equal to 10 (TRUE/FALSE).

[image]